Testing chrome os administration using VM's
Not sure if this is the correct place, but I am looking to try and install a Chrome OS in a VM. There's an answer form '11 where it says this is impossible but that seems long ago, so figured it's worth reasking.
The reason that's not the title of the question is that the Chrome OS in a VM is not the goal, it's just a stepping stone to what I actually want to do which is learn more about and test chromebook/chrome OS administration. So this might easily be an X/Y problem. Maybe there is some more reasonable way to get to the goal other than spinning up a VM. It just was the first thing I thought of. Any recommendation would be welcome.
